# hostapd: I want wpa3 only..but enable WEP!

Tags: hostapd, wpa, wpa3

I start hostapd for wpa3 only auth.

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=mysid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=iforgotit
wpa_key_mgmt=SAE
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

But when I do the scan

nmcli device wifi list it report...WEP!

```
nmcli device wifi list 
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID         MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        E****************  Mysid        Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   97      ▂▄▆█  WEP
```

Why?
How to disable wep?

edit1: i add this

auth_algs=1

but don't work, is still wep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: my hardware don't support wpa3 as AP
If I configure it as WPA2 the WEP disappear and WPA2 appear.
I prefer wpa3, but wpa2 is better than wep.

Another solution which works (On Slackware 15 with kernel 6.3 and module rtw_8821cu with [this hardware](https://www.brostrend.com/products/brostrend-ac650-linux-chiavetta-wifi-usb))

wpa2 conf

```
interface=wlan2
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=wpa2sid
hw_mode=g 
channel=7
#macaddr_acl=1
#accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
wmm_enable=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=yourpass!wpa2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

wpa3

```
interface=wlan2
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=wpa3ssid
hw_mode=g
channel=7
#macaddr_acl=1
#accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
wmm_enable=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=yourpass!wpa3
wpa_key_mgmt=SAE
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Comment: WPA2 is basically impossible to hack into (if your devices are updated and bug/vulnerabilities free), WEP is wide open. "Not more secure" is a **false** statement. If you can hack into my WPA2 network I will give you a good chunk of money right away.